# why WebView.loadUrl("javascript: someFunction()") don't work with local html files?

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I'm loading an HTML file from the SD card with android's `WebView.loadUrl()` method.
this html file contains JavaScript functions, souch as `someFunction()`.

from some reason I stil don't understand,  calling to `mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:someFunction()");` don't "trigger" the function in the HTML file. (I'm calling it after the html finished loading...)

when I'm loading to the web view **the same HTML file** from **remote server**, and launch the same javascript call from the webView - it does work!
so I know the problem got something with the fact that I'm loading it from local file, and not a bug in my html file.

I know about the need to enable javascript:

```
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

it doesn't help!

I've noticed also that there is the same problem with the `WebViewClient.onLoadResource()` callback.   it seems like I have general problem with the javascript when the files are local, and not from remote-server (or accessed from HTTP Web Server's uri, to be exact).

any suggestions why it happening, and what I need to do to make it work?

TIA

Comment: It certainly works when loading from assets: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/WebKit/GeoWeb2

Comment: @CommonsWare: loading from assets is not an option for my app, but anyway I've tried it also in some stage of the development - and it didn't work also. I believe your example works, so I think to myself what is the difference with my java code/ html files to yours. it seems the same both, although my html file is a player which comes with additional swf files, created with the articulate exporting plugin for power point presentations. the javascript function I'm adding to the html controlling switching of slides. is it suppose to make any different?

Comment: I have never tried embedding SWF on Android, so I have no idea if it would present an issue or not -- sorry!

Comment: @CommonsWare: thank you very much for linking me to your example. I'm stuck with this problem for a while, and was pretty sure it's just not possible from some security issues, or a bug with the API. your example contradicts that, and provide me something I can compare with, and maybe now I could finally see why I can't make it work. I will look more closely on your example, and try to find what's wrong with mine.

Comment: @CommonsWare  mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:someFunction(data)");   parameter passing supported like java? we can pass data to html by this "Injecting JavaScript into a WebView" ??

Comment: @Subra: The `someFunction(data)` needs to be valid JavaScript source code.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you.. so we can pass some value from activity to the webview!

Comment: @Subra: Yes, so long as it is in the form of literals in the JavaScript source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like it is was my mistake.    java script functions working even when the html file is on the SD.  it was that specific function I used simply didn't worked as accpected  from some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

how about mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:someFunction();");   ?
with ";"